# office web app -word viewing config in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps

office web app had installed on our SharePoint server but we do not have word viewing and powerpoint service in central admin - services on server  what can we do i need to config word viewing

best regards

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a few things.

Having office web apps installed, configured and connected to your farm is sufficent enough to view and edit office documents in the browser.
You dont need to configure additional sharepoint components like to word- or powerpoint service.

Please check first if your configuration is working:
http://[your office web apps/hosting/discovery

Check if you have completed all steps:

**On the office web apps server**

New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalURL "http://servername" -AllowHttp -EditingEnabled

**On the sharepoint server**

New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName  -AllowHTTP

**Source**

Office Web Apps - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455.aspx

SharePoint - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx